# Xcode font not printing letters with accent marks correctly

Tags: xcode

I'm using the font Apple SD Gothic Neo. The letters print fine except when I have one with an accent mark, like `ú`:

[image]

This is not a custom font, and it happens on all font weights. If it makes a difference, I'm pulling the string from Firebase.

Why is this happening and what can I do?

Comment: Hard to see how this is a programming question. Should be moved to Ask Different perhaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a different font.

When a font lacks a glyph, that glyph is substituted from another font, resulting in a typographical mismatch. That’s what’s happening here. You are using a font that is very Unicode-incomplete for Latin alphabet characters. It is intended for Korean! Use a more appropriate font.

Comment: Oh, alright thanks! Shame, I really liked that font!